# Can't insert data to Elasticsearch from Kafka Connect

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I've been trying to send Topic messages to Elasticsearch Indexes but keep receiving the same error no matter what parameters I changed, when i run this config with an empty topic, it actually creates index on the other side but when i write messages to topic, instead of copying them to elastic indexes it fails with the below error, I added parameters to ignore schemas, schema.ignore, key.ignore etc. and I also tried to use built in value.converter etc. but just can't make it run.

The Connector I run:

```
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
  "name": "pageviews3",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "pageviews2",
    "connection.url": "http://xxxxxxxxxx:9200",
    "type.name": "kafka-connect",
    "connection.username": "elastic",
    "connection.password": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}' http://xxxxx:8083/connectors`
```

Another Connector where i ignore schema registry etc.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
  "name": "page-views34",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "connection.url": "http://xxxx:9200",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "pageviews2",
    "type.name": "_doc",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "schema.ignore": "true",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "connection.username": "elastic",
    "connection.password": "xxxxxx"
  }
}' http://xxxxx:8083/connectors
```

I used default confluent datagenerator, it also creates schema for itself.

```
curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/datagen_local_02/config \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{
            "connector.class": "io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector",
            "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
            "kafka.topic": "pageviews2",
            "quickstart": "pageviews",
            "max.interval": 1000,
            "iterations": 10000000,
            "tasks.max": "1"
        }'
```

This is the error Output:

```
"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:223)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:149)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:493)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:332)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:234)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:203)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:244)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic pageviews2 to Avro: \n\tat io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:124)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:88)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$3(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:173)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:207)\n\t... 13 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.getByteBuffer(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:244)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.<init>(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:334)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:202)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(AvroConverter.java:172)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:107)\n\t... 17 more\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a brand new topic and start over. Your error is saying there's at least one event with a non Avro key or value

You can use `kafka-avro-console-consumer` to verify you have Avro data before deploying any sink connector

Then, I always suggest adding both key and value converters in your connector configs, even if you'll ignore the key via settings since Kafka Connect still needs to deserialize the data (or not, if you set ByteArrayConverter)

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try to use kafka-avro-console-consumer, then let you know. :)

Comment: Here are the new errors after changing the configuration, i would be really happy if you can check and say anything that can help :) 
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to execute bulk request due to ‘org.elasticsearch.common.compress.NotXContentException: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes’ after 6 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.compress.NotXContentException: Compresso

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Elasticsearch exceptions. Maybe there is a setting to disable compression?